# IIS7 proxying VisualSVN server refuses to allow Web.config files to be committed

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, web.config, visualsvn-server, arr

I use IIS 7.5 with the Application Request Routing and URL Rewriting modules to act as a reverse proxy for several apache-based web sites, including VisualSVN Server. I'm having a problem when I try to commit a Web.config file, TortoiseSVN gives me the following error:

> Sending content: C:\Users\Tim
>   Long\Desktop[obfuscated]\www\1\admin\Comments\Web.config   Error:
>   Commit failed (details follow):   Error:
>   '/svn/TiGra/!svn/wrk/852c5a84-a682-2847-8b29-6d5b353ff786/trunk/Webs/[obfuscated]/www/1/admin/Comments/Web.config'
>   Error: path not found   Finished!:

In the IIS logs, I see a 404 not found:

> ```
> 2011-08-05 17:47:05 192.168.162.52 PUT /svn/TiGra/!svn/wrk/852c5a84-a682-2847-8b29-6d5b353ff786/trunk/Webs/[obfuscated]/www/1/admin/Comments/Web.config - 80 - 192.168.162.35 SVN/1.6.17+(r1128011)/TortoiseSVN-1.6.16.21511+neon/0.29.6 404 8 0 0
> ```

I suspect this is because IIS is configured to disallow `*.config` files from being served. I've edited the request filtering rules for the site and explicitly allowed `.config` files, I've also added a MIME type of `text/plain`, but no joy.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get IIS to correctly allow `Web.config` files to pass transparently through to the back-end VisualSVN server?

Comment: Ah, found a solution - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483531/iis7-and-arr-as-reverse-proxy-for-subversion